# Bad url request while sending GET request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

```
http://<url>/<abc>.php?email=<email_id>&datadict=<json dictionary>&id=<id>
```

Above is my get request url i am sending in GET. But xcode is creating 'Bad Url' error.
I have already used NSUTF8StringEncoding for creating a valid url.
i am developing for ios 6.
Can anyone help me??

Following is my code :

```
serviceUrl = @"http://<url>/<abc>.php?

NSMutableString* theString = [NSMutableString string];

[theString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@email=",serviceUrl]];

[theString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myDict objectForKey:@"email"]]];
[theString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&datadict=%@&",[myDict objectForKey:@"confirmation"]]]; 
 //paypal payment gateway confirmation in json
//NSString* udidEncoded = [[myDict objectForKey:@"udid"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[theString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"udid=%@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString]];
NSLog(@"concat : %@", theString);


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:900.0];

return request;
```

Comment: @Cfreak please help i hv posted code also.

Comment: if the url is of staging development server can you please NSLog "theString" and paste it here

Comment: Does this url work if you put it into a browser?

Comment: [TheString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] use this insted of the string while making url

Comment: @amar i am getting following in response according to your suggestion: error is The operation couldn’t be completed.(Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: NSLog theString and put it in browser and see if you are getting any response there.

Comment: i m not getting any response.
I know the problem is at device end while making request. but what could be the possible reasons for it?